# Encoding lost on save

Tags: powershell, web, encoding

I want to save output from a web site and encoding is lost.

Here is the script, `test.ps1`, requires `curl.exe` ([cinst curl](https://chocolatey.org/packages/curl))

```
$content     = 'kuca'

$url         = "https://www.slovomajstor.com/wmst/http?app=transliterator&request=transliterate&reqLang=sr-bald&targetLang=sr-latn"
$refer       = "Referer: https://www.slovomajstor.com/index.latn.html"
$contentType = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=UTF-8"

curl.exe $url -H $contentType -H $refer --data "$content"
```

This is the output visible in ConEmu (its font is Courier new with encoding East Europe in case its relevant).

```
<span kon:baldWord='kuca' ... kon:options='kuća,kuca,kuča'>kuća</span>
```

If I now run `./test.ps1 | Out-File out.html -Encodiong whatever` it comes out as a garbage. Browser shows up `ku─ça` instead of `kuća`.

What to do ?

Comment: `[Console]::OutputEncoding=[Text.Encoding]::UTF8`

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot.